# SQL calculate ratio between counts from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:
Products with columns id, description
Demands with columns id, branch
Stock with columns id, branch

I want to calculate the ratio for each product and branch, and get something like this

```
product branch demands stock ratio
shoes   A      4       8     2
shoes   B      8       4     0.5
shirts  A      1       1     1
```

I thought this would be easy, but I got stuck after this

```
SELECT products.id, products.description,demands.branch, COUNT(demands.branch)
FROM products
LEFT JOIN demands ON (demands.id=products.id)
WHERE demands.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY products.id, demands.branch
```

There could be demands where there is nothing in stock, and I'm working with an mySQL-database embedded in an administrative system

Comment: Sample data would be a big help.  You mention three tables, but your query has only two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one method uses `union all`:

```
select id, branch, sum(demand), sum(stock), sum(stock) / nullif(sum(demand), 0) as ratio
from ((select id, branch, 1 as demand, 0 as stock
       from demands
      ) union all
      (select id, branch, 0 as demand, 1 as stock
       from stock
      )
     ) ds
group by id, branch;
```